# Android discussion board

Tags: android, mailing-list

Is there any good and often visited developer Android discussion board? I saw that the Google has just an mailing list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/resources/community-groups.html), the official question/answer board is some website called [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/). There are also a bunch of mailing lists which may be subscribed to for discussions.

Comment: It seems I should edit this since Google seems to have switched to G+ based support. Honestly, I like things better when this answer was true.

Answer (score 0):

There is [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) with over 10.000 questions on android. Buf if you are looking for something where you can have a discussion in the old fashioned kind instead of asking questions I don't know a good one.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for answers... 

I will use the stackoverflow.com, which is GREAT, even I was looking for the Android specific DiBo, as the mailing list on android developer community I did not found to be a good way to find answers for any questions quickly (~ day). Plus it is recommended by Google as one you noted.

Even the mailing list might not be a good place to ask, it is a first place to search in the case of questions.

The www.talkandroid.com is not visited too often by developers. 

The http://www.xda-developers.com/ has also something, but still not enough to be the 

BR
STeN

Answer (score 0):

There are [android developer community](http://developer.android.com/community/index.html) and [talkandroid](http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/android-development/).

I have also found the Android section of [xda-developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/) useful

Answer (score 0):

You are at the right place. Android is a sponsored tag (I think by Google) on stackoverflow.com

Pose your question and you should get an answer in minutes. 
You can then carry on the discussion through comments to the answer.